# Keeping an insignificant control variable (with little variation) in FE Regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, econometrics, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I am running a FE regression with state-level data focusing on the impact of a particular law. I
have two control variables for different laws that are binary indicating if the law was in place in state s, at time t. One of the control coefficients is not statistically significant but the other one is. Only 4 out of 49 states have a change in the insignificant law during the 25 year time period (the others are either a constant 1 or 0). Additionally, when I ran a linear hypothesis test with the null hypothesis that: b control1 = b control2 
in the model where it was just those two variables + my focus independent variable, I was able to reject the null. However, when I added an additional control variable (the proportion of Democrats in the state senate) I was unable to reject the null (P=0.18).

I am unsure exactly what to do with this information. Should I keep the insignificant variable in the regression since I initially theorized the law should be controlled for or should I remove it because of what I said above? The coefficients on the other independent variables change slightly when I remove it. Does keeping it in the regression bias my results?